# Silverlight memories

Tags: c#, silverlight, memory-leaks

Why so much memory in Silverlight?

Data:

I am having many check boxes and others on USER INTERFACE sometimes. As matter of course, I am removing check boxes and other controls from visuals, but the memory usage of Silverlight always increases; it never decreases.

How do I ensure memory is released?

Is this a problem with garbage collection? How do I find root of all remaining objects with
no reference that are not yet collected?

I can provide more data if it is needed.

Comment: How do you create and remove those controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory management engine that Silverlight uses is similar to the one that the CLR uses for WPF and other traditional .NET applications.  It is based on garbage collection and if you maintain references to objects, even accidentally, that prevents them from being garbage collected, then memory consumption will continue to increase.

If you have this problem in your Silverlight application you can look around for leaks or you can try to use tools to look for leaks and to find where most of the memory is being allocated.  Probably the quickest way is with a memory profiler.  Unfortunately there are not a lot of memory profilers that work with Silverlight but the ANTS profiler, which has a free trial version, supposedly does:

- [ANTS Memory Profiler 7.0](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/)

Comment: i have already been using the ANTS it shows object never collected but that is help

Answer (score 3):

The most common cause for run away memory is not detaching event handlers from elements that have been removed from the object tree.

Something often evades notice is that instance level fields (including the delegates that implement events) on the application object and the `MainPage` (or whatever is being use as the `RootVisual`) are as good as `static` fields since they typically live as long as the app does.

Hence an innocent looking:-

```
btn.Click += btn_myClickHandler;
```

in the code of the main page can lead to a memory leak if `btn` is removed from the UI without a corresponding:-

```
btn.Click -= btn_myClickHandler;
```

Comment: Wow, good advice. I must say I don't really have memory problems, but this is something I would probably not think of when I would debug for memory problems.

Comment: i am knowing of this.. has already been attempt with no help. some other referenc exists